# Using WFFM to create a user to a custom user profile

Tags: wffm, user-management, user-profile

I'm trying to use WFFM to create a user registration form for my site. I've created a custom domain to put the users in, and added a few fields to a custom user profile. Then I created my form and hooked up the "create new user" save action. In the "additional user properties" section, I see the User Profile section, but the dropdown for User Profile fields aren't my fields.

Is there any way to do the mapping I want to do? I know through the API and a custom form I can do it easily, but we'll be doing internationalization with this site, and we're already using WFFM, so I thought I'd take advantage of built-in capabilities where possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Actions/Save Actions/Create User` item, there's a parameter for DefaultProfileItemId. This is set to the profile ID to use. To connect to your own, either change this value, or duplicate the action so the default "Create User" action isn't changed.

There does appear to be an issue though, as I did this but it didn't switch in the form designer to use my user profile, even though I changed the parameter. I've got a query into Sitecore support about it.

UPDATE: Sitecore support said "Please try setting your custom user profile in the User Profile field of your form item. I tried this locally and the custom profile fields appeared in the Create User action editor." - this worked.